# Мобильные приложения. Что нужно знать?

Tags: мобильные-приложения, java, c++, мобильная-разработка

Здарова, бандиты, хочу задать очень банальный и весьма "сложный" вопрос. У меня есть куча идей для мобильных приложений, я хочу их реализовать, но заплатить команде разработчиков я не хочу, ибо материальная часть дорога. Собственно вопрос: какой же язык(-и) программирования нужно изучать, чтобы создавать приложения для Android и iOS (для iOS -  Objective C, я знаю, но, может, что-то еще?). Хватит обычных С++ и Java?

Comment: Скупой платит дважды. Если у вас нет реального интереса к программированию, оно у вас не пойдёт, и вы зря потратите время.

Оставьте программирование тем, кто это любит.

Comment: Плохо, уважаемый, вы меня знаете =)

Comment: @Ghostthekroul, вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе.

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы писать хорошие программы\приложения, нужно изучать программирование лет 5 минимум. Конечно, уже через месяц чтения разных книг и мануалов возможно будете спасобны что-то совсем простое писать, но чтобы вникнуть в процесс и понять разные тонкости, нужно немало времени.

Про дизайн: как я понимаю, Вы собираетесь быть разработчиком одиночкой, то, помимо кода, надо уметь и дизайном заниматься, ибо особенно приложения мобильных платформ должны его иметь. Конечно, все изначально выглядит просто, пока не начнешь его сам разрабатывать, там тоже масса своих тонкостей и сложностей. В этом плане для настольных ПК чуть проще с дизайном, но тоже иногда можно потратить уйму времени на его разработку и подстройку под конкретное решение.

По поводу заработка: все относительно, можно ничего не заработать на iOS, а на Android преуспеть, все зависит от приложения, способов монетизации и так далее.

По поводу "хватит **обычных** С++ и Javа": поумерьте пыл и возьмитесь за одну платформу с одним языком, ибо и на одном научиться писать уже немалое достижение.

Поэтому советую подумать и все взвесить, не самый простой путь. Если сможет пропитаться к программированию особыми чувствами, тогда я в Вас не сомневаюсь, что преуспеете.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ =)
Понимаю, что быстро ничего не делается, что ж буду стараться.

Comment: Да не нужно ничего изучать уже пять лет...
Нужно внимательно смотреть как пишут другие и читать книги.
С одной платформой люто плюсую!

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от платформы. Android - Java, iOS - Obj C.

Но тут проблема еще в том, что обе эти платформы достаточно разные, и потребуются много времени, чтобы изучить и прочувствовать хотя бы одну из них.

В общем, начните с наиболее популярной OS Android для большего покрытия рынка (так же у Android ниже порог вхождения), однако надо учитывать специфику его рынка, а именно банальное нищебродство многих его пользователей, что не может не накладывать определенные финансовые ограничения на продажу софта в маркете.

Comment: Спасибо, четко и ясно =)

Answer (score 0):

Разрешите мне порекомендовать Вам, почитать статью: [А тот ли ты путь выбрал, разработчик?](http://forum.startandroid.ru/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=3408)